# Store key / value of NSMutableDictionary to another NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

So I have three NSMutableDictionary's like this:

.h file

```
NSMutableDictionary *myContainer;
NSMutableDictionary *myD1;
NSMutableDictionary *myD2;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *myContainer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *myD1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *myD2;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize myContainer;
@synthesize myD1;
@synthesize myD2;
```

( init )

```
self.myContainer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.myD1        = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.myD2        = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Now I want to add values or positions in the dictionary to myContainer from myD1 and myD2

Pseudo:

```
[myD1 setValue:foo forKey:@"bar"];
[foo retain];

[myD2 setValue:hello forKey:@"world"];
[hello retain];
```

So my question is how do I add specific key / value to myD1 and / or myD2 to myContainer? And then retrieve the key / value from them as well?

The below looks like what I need but I'm a newbie and the format I have differs.

Coming from PHP here is how I would structure this:

```
$myContainer   = array();
$myD1          = array();
$myd2          = array();

$myD1['bar']   = 'foo';
$myD2['world'] = 'hello';

$myContainer['common_index'] = array($myD1, $myD2);

// Alternative
//$myContainer['common_index'] = array(0 => $myD1, 1 => $myD2);

// Retrieving values from $myD1
echo "Value: ".$myContainer['common_index'][0]['bar']."\n";
echo "Value: ".$myContainer['common_index'][1]['world']."\n";

// Alternative
foreach($myContainer['common_index'] as $array) {
    foreach($array as $index => $value) {
        echo "Index: {$index} Value: {$value} \n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value: foo
Value: hello
Index: bar Value: foo 
Index: world Value: hello
```

Related:

- [NSMutableDictionary with single key holding many values in Objective-C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437881/nsmutabledictionary-with-single-key-holding-many-values-in-objective-c-programmi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your myD1 myD2 dictionaries in an Array and set it to the myContainer dictionary as below :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:myD1, myD2, nil];
[myContainer setObject:array forKey:@"common_index"];
```

And for retreiving them :

```
NSMutableDictionary *myD1Retrieved = [[myContainer objectForKey:@"common_index"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableDictionary *myD2Retrieved = [[myContainer objectForKey:@"common_index"] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

To add data to myContainer:

```
[myContainer setValue:[mD1 valueForKey:@"bar"] forKey:@"bar"];
[myContainer setValue:[mD2 valueForKey:@"world"] forKey:@"world"];
```

For retrieval from myContainer:

```
Object *firstObject = [myContainer valueForKey:@"world"];
Object *secondObject = [myContainer valueForKey:@"bar"];
```

`Object` stands for the type of value for world and bar keys.

go on..